# Ansible playbook failing due to "The conditional check ''not found' in command_output.stdout' failed"

Tags: python, ansible, conditional-statements, conda

My playbook runs fine when conda is not installed but runs into the following error if it is installed:

```
TASK [Ensure `base` environment uses Python 3.9] ********************************
```

> fatal: [my_machine]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check ''not found' in command_output.stdout' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ('not found' in command_output.stdout): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/ansible/tasks/install-miniconda.yaml': line 25, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Ensure `base` environment uses Python 3.9\n  ^ here\n"}

If conda is found to be installed, it skips tasks previous to this step and fails here.

```
  - import_tasks: tasks/check-command.yaml
    vars:
      command: conda
  - import_tasks: tasks/install-miniconda.yaml
    vars:
      install_dir: "~/"
    when: "'not found' in command_output.stdout"
```

```
---
- name: Download miniconda
  ansible.builtin.get_url:
    url: https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
    dest: "{{ install_dir }}miniconda.sh"
    mode: 0644

- name: Setup .local/opt
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: ~/.local/opt
    state: directory
    mode: u=rwx,go=rx

- name: Install miniconda  # noqa no-changed-when
  ansible.builtin.shell: |
    /bin/bash {{ install_dir }}miniconda.sh -b -p ~/.local/opt/miniconda3
    . ~/.local/opt/miniconda3/bin/activate
    conda init bash

- import_tasks: login-shell.yaml
  vars:
    name: Check `base` environment Python version
    command: python --version

- name: Ensure `base` environment uses Python 3.9
  ansible.builtin.command: conda install -n base python=3.9
  when: 'command_output.stdout is not regex("^Python 3.9.\d+$")'

- name: Cleanup conda install script
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ install_dir }}miniconda.sh"
    state: absent
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'`, which seems like a clear error message.  You haven't shown us where you're setting the `command_output` variable, so we can only guess about the problem, but is the task that sets `command_output` getting skipped? In that case, you'll need to either check first that `command_output.stdout` is defined, or check if the task was skipped (`when: command_output is not skipped and ...`)

Comment: `The error was: error while evaluating conditional ('not found' in command_output.stdout): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'` indicates that a variable becomes not registered fully as it should.

Answer (score 1):

There are more problems:

- The error is: **'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'**. Take a look at the dictionary and fix it.
- For some reason, Python2 writes the version to stderr. For example,

```yaml
    - command: python --version
      register: command_output
    - debug:
        var: command_output
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  command_output:
    ansible_facts:
      discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python3
    changed: true
    cmd:
    - python
    - --version
    delta: '0:00:00.004342'
    end: '2022-08-12 22:51:57.467916'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2022-08-12 22:51:57.463574'
    stderr: Python 2.7.18
    stderr_lines:
    - Python 2.7.18
    stdout: ''
    stdout_lines: []
```

As a result, the condition below will be always *true*

```yaml
        - debug:
            msg: Run conda install -n base python=3.9
          when: 'command_output.stdout is not regex('^Python 3.9.\d+$')'
```

Fix it by using *shell* and redirecting stderr to stdout. For example,

```yaml
    - shell: python --version 2>&1
      register: command_output
    - debug:
        var: command_output
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  command_output:
    changed: true
    cmd: python --version 2>&1
    delta: '0:00:00.004157'
    end: '2022-08-12 22:57:10.841659'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2022-08-12 22:57:10.837502'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: Python 2.7.18
    stdout_lines:
    - Python 2.7.18
```

- Use [*version*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions) to test the versions. For example,

```yaml
    - name: Ensure base environment uses Python 3.9
      debug:
        msg: Run conda install -n base python=3.9
      when: python_version is version('3.9', '<')
      vars:
        python_version: "{{ command_output.stdout.split()|last }}"
```

- Generally, there might be more versions of Python installed in the system. Use the variable *ansible_python_version* if you want to find out the version Ansible is using. Otherwise, make sure the path in the command `python --version` is what you want.